# How to format this line according to PEP 8?

Tags: python, coding-style, pep8

I'm trying to adhere to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation), with a 78 character limit on the length of my lines.

I have the following statement:

```
startTime = time.strptime(request.GET.get('st', (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")), "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

How should I format it so that it adheres to PEP8 (where should I break it into new lines?)

Comment: Cross post of [How to format this line according to PEP 8?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/205917)

Comment: See the comments on the other post. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
startTime = time.strptime(
    request.GET.get(
        'st', 
        (
            dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
        ).strftime("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
    ),
    "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"
)
```

This one solution, but you use more variables for this. For example:

```
time_format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S"
yesterday_date = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1
```

This would make the code more readable

Answer (score 1):

Avoid writing such overly convoluted code in the first place:

```
if 'st' in request.GET:
    startTime = time.strptime(request.GET['st'], "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
else:
    startTime = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)).timetuple()
```

Why generate a default to be parsed out to a timetuple again instead of just going there straight?

Answer (score 0):

Split it up into different variables:

```
a_date = (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
req = request.GET.get('st', a_date)
startTime = time.strptime(req, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```